# Moving data by length

Tags: sql, mysql

I have to move **words** table's data to another tables.

For example words table is :

```
------------------------------
| word             | type    |
|------------------|---------|
| car              | NA      |
| home             | NA      |
| question         | PR      |
------------------------------
```

I have to move this data by length . For example , **car**'s length is *3* , and *car* will move to **3-char** table (with *type* column). And **question** will moved to **8-char** .

How can i do it with *SQL commands* .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of an incomplete question, but something like this might help point you in the right direction:

```
INSERT INTO words_3char SELECT word FROM all_words WHERE LENGTH(word)=3;

DELETE FROM all_words WHERE LENGTH(word)=3;
```

Comment: Yes.  For a one-time SQL management like this, I'd just copy/paste/edit these lines manually ~15 times or whatever your max word length is.

Comment: Eray, what are you trying to do, there must be a better way to do it?

Comment: @Toby , Just an example for improve my SQL knowledge. I don't use this method directly :) But thank you for your interest :)

Comment: not exactly . Actually , i'm thinking create a web game. This game is a word puzzle . I have to get 3-char words and 4-char words seperately, for example .

Comment: @dkamins this isn't working. **Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**

Comment: Eray, the where clause in a SQL. Statement will let you differentiate without having them in separate tables

Comment: @Eray If you include your table defs in your question, we could provide you working code.  Since you didn't, you have to extrapolate from the answers here.  And P.S. you should probably not be doing this in the first place.  Just SELECT ... WHERE LENGTH(word)=3 at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to ask why you need to do all this moving around, but I'm not sure its a good idea.  Assuming it is, take a look at the [Length()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) function for mysql and then try something like this.

```
Insert into table_Char3(Word) Values (
       Select Word from Words where Length(word) = 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move them to **new** tables like this

```
create table word1char as select word from words where length(trim(word)) = 1
..
create table word3chars as select word from words where length(trim(word)) = 3
```